# Setting alpha for text color for Button

Tags: android, button, user-interface, alpha

I tried setting `textColor` to have alpha, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/multi_player"
    android:text="@string/multi_player"
    android:textColor="#AAFFFFFF" />
```

No matter what alpha level I give it, the text still shows up as fully opaque white.

Comment: Humor me: Try moving it to a resource file (using `<color name="blah">#aaffffff</color>`), then include it (with `@color/blah`). I seem to recall seeing a similar problem fixed in this manner. (On one particular OS version; which are you testing on?)

Comment: Huh, that worked. Interesting. I am using android 4.0.3 ICS. Make your comment into an answer and then I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be an issue on (some versions of) Android, where alpha is not considered when set using `#rgb` or `#argb` formats.

Instead, move it to a resource file:

```
<color name="blah">#aaffffff</color>
```

Then, call it using:

```
android:textColor="@color/blah"
```